# How would I select a part of a class and replace it with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to select the class p100 and replace it with a number that will be inputted by the user, does anyone know how to keep the "p" and replace the number in the class using jQuery?

```
<div class="c100 p100 small green storyline">
```

Comment: something like this can be done: $('.p100').removeClass('p100').addClass('p'+uservalue);

Comment: @techLove type your comment as an answer so the OP can accept it

Comment: will `p100` always be the second classname or are you gonna have something like this `<div class="c100 small p100 green storyline">` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this can be done: `$('.p100').removeClass('p100').addClass('p'+uservalue);`

edit:
if you have more that one div with class p100:

```
$('.p100').each(function(){
  $(this).removeClass('p100').addClass('p'+uservalue);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var item = $('.p100');

$('#button').click(() => {
  item.removeClass('p100');
  item.addClass('p200')
})
```

[Working JSFiddle with visuals](https://jsfiddle.net/9g6ms9av/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the class by using .attr(), like this:

```
$("#td_id").attr('class', 'newClass');
```

If you want to add a class, use .addclass() instead, like this:

```
$("#td_id").addClass('newClass');
```

Or a short way to swap classes using .toggleClass():

```
$("#td_id").toggleClass('change_me newClass');
```

> Read more about [Class attributes](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/)

Answer (score 0):

Using `String.match` & `RegExp.test`

```js
var pattern = new RegExp("/p[0-9]*/");
var className = $('div').attr('class')
if (pattern.test(className)) {
    var class = className.match(pattern)[0];
    $('div').removeClass(class).addClass('p' + integer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers mention good ways with jquery, I'd like to add a vanilla javascript solution :) :

```
for(let elem of document.getElementsByClassName('p100'){
    elem.classList.remove('p100');
    elem.classList.add('p'+uservalue);
}
```

If you want to restrict it to `div`s (the above code will match every element with class `p100`) just replace `document.getElementsByClassName('p100')` with `document.querySelectorAll('div .p100')` :).

We could replace the two calls of `.remove` and `.add` with one call of `.replace` like this :  `elem.classList.replace('p100','p'+uservalue)`, Currently this function isn't implemented in all browsers.

Pay attention that `classList` is supported in IE10+, if you need IE9 support you need a polyfill, MDN already gives one and the polyfill provides `replace` function above too, see here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList (scroll down to see the polyfill)

for `document.querySelectorAll` support, it's supported in IE8(CSS2 selectors only) and IE9+(all CSS selectors including CSS3 ones).